# My AGP GeForce2 does nothing while compiz eats up all my CPU time

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, compiz

Ubuntu 14.04 (i386) can not accept NVidia Geforce2 MX 400

The "nouveau" driver does not use the nvidia capabilities on my AGP GeForce2 card, so Unity (`compiz`) eats up all my CPU time.

I tried to install nvidia drivers, but I haven't found one that works. I installed Metacity

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

so now I may choose Metacity instead of Unity, and that leaves me with some more CPU to work with. In my opinion, this is not a good solution.

The nvidia card is able to offload loads of CPU, but does not have a driver any more? Because it's "too old"? Too old says who? The guys who wants to sell you something? 
Please tell me that I'm wrong.

CPU 2GHz Intel Pentium 4 with 1.2 GB RAM on an ASUS P4533 motherboard. Still going strong.

When I do:
`sudo lshw -C video`

I get:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NV11 [GeForce2 MX/MX 400]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm agp agp-2.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=64 maxlatency=1 mingnt=5
       resources: irq:16 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:efff0000-efffffff
```

Seems to be a favourite question...

Thanks Miro, Drac Noc, KeepingUp and Emre Doğan, but I'm still facing the wall...

Comment: The nouveau drivers are more efficient on legacy hardware than Nvidia's anyway. Best bet is to install LXDE or Cinnamon, as they are more efficient

Comment: Thanks Seth for the nice formatting! And to Geary for your LXDE and Cinnamon comment! I heard about lubuntu, ChrunchBang and antiX also, so I guess I'll have to start to evaluate, if searching a driver is hopeless. I'm hoping to connect my old Yamaha PSS 780 midi keyboard once the system monitor tells that there are some CPU cycles free to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look [at this benchmark](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce2%20MX%2FMX%20400) to see what your problem is...  Although plain vanilla Ubuntu requires a GPU, yours is just not up to the task any more.  If I were in your position I wouldn't evaluate anything and just go straight for Lubuntu as this will give you a stable and well-supported environment for years to come.

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...  :-(